# How to export databasee from amazon dynamodb and import into redis?

Tags: database, redis, amazon-dynamodb

I want to migrate my database from dynamodb to redis. I could not find a connection between export mechanism of dynamodb and import in redis.
I would appreciate your answer about steps to follow.

Comment: Redis is a cache, not a database; this is not an answer, just wanted to make sure you're aware that Redis serves a different purpose than DynamoDB is designed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a script say in Python that reads the data from DybamoDb and brings it in memory and then the same script writes it to your Redis store as well. You don't need any direct connection between the two DBs. Make sure you do some sort of batching if there is a lot of data to be inserted at once in redis to prevent any timeouts. ( like if u have 10000 keys to hmset in redis, u are probably better off using batching and processing say 100  keys at once rather than 10k )

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to do this in javascript?

Comment: The process is similar in javascript as well. Just search for the relevant modules / clients for read / write from dynamo and redis and the logic is fairly simple --> Read from dynamo, form the proper key,value pair for redis and write to redis.